# Using Rapids with kmeans imputation in python

Tags: knn, rapids, cuml

I was just wondering if anyone has been able to successfully use rapids with knn imputation. I know cuml.impute was avaliable perviously but is seems like it has not been removed. If anyone has a suggestion that would be great.

I tried using cuml.impute but it didn't work.

Comment: cuML has not implemented an accelerated version of scikit-learn's KNNImputer as of the 23.02 release. If this would be useful to you, could you please comment on [this Github issue](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/4694) with information about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for anyone else, I have received a response from the cuml people and they basically said it is not a priority right now but any user made solutions are welcome.